# Nontrivial closed ideal of $\mathbb{B(H)}$, $\mathbb{H}$ is a non-separable Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

$\mathbb{H}$ is a non-separable Hilbert space. Give an example of nontrivial closed ideal $I$of  $\mathbb{B(H)}$, that is different from $\mathbb{B_0(H)}$ which is the ideal of compact operators.

Any disscussion would me welcomed!    Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: A complete characterization of closed, two-sided ideals in $B(H)$ is discussed in the following post on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124270/bh-as-a-direct-sum-of-a-closed-two-sided-ideal-and-a-subalgebra/124280#124280.

Comment: @MaoWao       thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can see the ideal of compact operators as the ideal generated by the finite-rank operators. You can play the same game and consider the ideal generated by those operators which have separable range (or any other cardinality less than the dimension of $\mathbb H$).

Answer (score 1):

You will find complete descriptions of all closed ideals in the papers

> M. Daws, [Closed ideals in the Banach algebra of operators on classical non-separable spaces](https://matthewdaws.github.io/mathematics/files/ideals.pdf), *Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc.* **140** (2006), no. 2, 317–332.
>
> W.B. Johnson, T. Kania, G. Schechtman, Closed ideals of operators on and complemented subspaces of Banach spaces of functions with countable support, [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03026) (2015).